# How to mock imported objects in jest?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm having trouble mocking an object differently in two different it blocks. Both blocks end up getting the same mock (in this case where `environment: 'development'`).

Is there a way to do this? I am aware of mockImplementationOnce but that's for functions.
Thank you for any advice or guidance!

```
describe('myTest', () => {
  it('should return true if environment is development', () => {


   jest.mock('@alias/config', () => {
     const config = require.requireActual('@alias/config');
    return {
      ...config,
      environment: 'development'
    }})
    expect(myTest().toEqual(true);
  });

  it('should return false if environment is not development', () => {
    
   jest.mock('@alias/config', () => {
      const config = require.requireActual('@alias/config');
    return {
      ...config,
      environment: 'production'
    }})
    expect(myTest().toEqual(false);
  });

  });
});
```

Comment: did you try resetting mocks before each test? `beforeEach(() => { jest.resetAllMocks(); });`

Comment: @Nikki9696 Yes, no luck there